# PDDL: Exact meaning of effects and conditions in durative-actions

Tags: planning, pddl

In PDDL 2.1, `durative-action`s were introduced. They are described (amongst others) with `conditon`s and `effect`s. Both can be defined `at start`/`at end`, `condition` also `over all`.

I found the following document, describing PDDL 2.1 quite extensively: [pddl2.1 : An Extension to pddl for Expressing Temporal Planning Domains](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.4561).  Nevertheless, I have some problems getting the exact meaning.

The paper gives the following example:

```
    (:durative-action heat-water
        :parameters (?p - pan)
        :duration (= ?duration (/ (- 100 (temperature ?p)) (heat-rate)))
        :condition (and (at start (full ?p))
            (at start (onHeatSource ?p))
            (at start (byPan))
            (over all (full ?p))
            (over all (onHeatSource ?p))
            (over all (heating ?p))
            (at end (byPan)))
        :effect (and
            (at start (heating ?p))
            (at end (not (heating ?p)))
            (at end (assign (temperature ?p) 100)))
    )
```

I'm wondering, whether `(at start (onHeatSource ?p))` is redundant, as there is also the statement `(over all (onHeatSource ?p))`. If not, where is the difference?

What is the order of evaluation? `condition at start`, `effect at start`, `effect at end`, `condition at end`? Does `over all` include the time instance `at start` and `at end`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is actually answered in the very same article that you cite. On page 12 (or 72) you find the explanation:

> Invariant conditions in a durative action are required to hold over an
>   interval that is open at both ends (starting and ending at the end
>   points of the action). These are expressed using the *over all*
>   construct seen in Figures 6 and 8. If one wants to specify that a fact
>   `p` holds in the closed interval over the duration of a durative action,
>   then three conditions are required: `(at start p)`, `(over all p)` and `(at end p)`.

Thus I think there is nothing more one needs to explain.

Concerning your second question:

> What is the order of evaluation? condition at start, effect at start,
>   effect at end, condition at end? Does over all include the time
>   instance at start and at end?

The last question was answered before: `over all` is an *open* interval. For the rest, i.e. the question about the order of the evaluation, I do not understand the question -- it seems to make no sense to me. *Conditions* are criteria that are required to hold in order for the action to be applicable. But in contrast to non-durative actions, these criteria are not just evaluated in the specific state in which it is applied to, but over a sequence of states. To which states these conditions apply is specified by the key words `at start`, `at end`, and `over all`.

The *effects* are not evaluated, but they "happen", i.e. they specify how the resulting state (in `at end`) changes as a consequence of this action application.

-- hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for answering the first question. The cited paragraph answers my question very well, I had not found it.

I would say the point of evaluation matters in the sense that an effect can alter a condition: If the effect `at end` sets e. g. a variable `x` to 1 (that was 0 before), a condition `at end` that checks for equality `x == 1` is either satisfied (it it is evaluated after the effect) or not (if evaluated before).